# Show previously attached file in HTML form while editing

Tags: html, django, forms

I am writing a Django application where I have a HTML form to get a few inputs from the user. One of the inputs is an (optional) attachment file. The user is also provided with option to edit the form at some point in future.

When the user chooses to edit the form, the Django `view` returns the `ModelForm` and in the `template` I populate all the fields. But I am not able to populate the attachment in the file `input` tag. However, I can see that the form object has the attachment in it.

I found a few SO questions which asks for attaching a new file using scripts. And that is not possible due to security reasons. But I am looking for populating the file returned by the server on HTML page.

Is there a way to populate attached files with `input` tags?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that. Instead what you do is provide a link to existing file and a separate input box for a new file in case the user needs it.